Transparency doesn't work properly (Cycles)
I have rendered this image as a PNG with RGBA, while having Transparency checked in "Film". The Render Result in Blenders window looks promising (1st image), but as soon as I save the image, it looks like this (2nd image). Like the fire, that is missing a background object suddenly gets almost invisible. Is there something I forgot to check?

Your PNG can't keep the emission color over the transparency

Is there a way to circumvent it?

moonboots is correct ... Probably render image with Emmision pass enabled and merge this pass into alpha channel? ... but PNG will never blend with background colours correctly. You should render into EXR format and composite render onto BG in an app that supports emmisive pixels.

Or just adjust (contrast) alpha channel in any image editor https://imgur.com/1cfUQvC

you can use tricks like render with a black background, then render a b&w mask with the shape only, then mix in your video software with the layer set on Add, etc...

Emission (your flame) is not the same as occlusion (Alpha). See this image for an illustration of that: https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/lighting-candle-long-shadow-against-canvas-116225665

Probably doesn't ... I can also imagine better result, but since we dont know too much about your blend file setup, it can be also some Color Management issue or what ever.

Anyway if you check your PNG's RGB (without Alpha channel) all the fire is there ...

... also Alpha contains semitransparent pixels of originaly emmissive pixels.

So, you can use some contrasting the Alpha channel to get it back.


Note: PNG will never blend with background colours properly. You should render into EXR format and composite render onto BG in an app that supports emmisive pixels.
